# See binding errors in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms

I am running into problems from time to time with View -> ViewModel binding errors with Xamarin.Forms on iOS.

For instance, I had a binding from a label to a double property in the ViewModel and just nothing happened until I added a string format like this:

```
myLabel.SetBinding<MyViewModel> (Label.TextProperty, vm => vm.MyDoubleProperty, stringFormat: "{0:0.0}");
```

It would have been a lot easier if the framework told me that there was an error.

And this is my question: Where can I see binding exceptions / warnings in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding errors are reported in the `Debug` log, i.e. the `Output` pad in your IDE:
[image]

The particular conversion issue might not be reported as an error at the moment, but this is currently being worked out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Stephane. This was were I looked. Thought there was another place or some kind of tracing event. But I am happy to hear that there are plans for improvements :-)

Comment: I'm not seeing binding errors in the Application Output pad.  Is there something you need to do to enable this?

Comment: Me neither, @Teevus